# Override a django third-party application template through extend

Tags: django, django-templates, overriding, pinax

I'm using third-party apps (through Pinax), and I am trying to override a template file that the third-party template extends from.

That is --

```
Third party app:
    templates/app/a.html
    templates/base.html

My project:
    templates/app/b.html
    templates/base.html
```

Where I've copied and modified `base.html` from the third-party app for use in my own project and both the third-party `app/a.html` and my own `app/b.html` do `{% extends "base.html" %}`.

The current behavior is that when `app/a.html` extends `base.html`, it's currently loading the third-party `base.html`, while `app/b.html` is loading my own `base.html`.  The preferred behavior is for both `app/a.html` and `app/b.html` to load my `base.html`.

Is there a way to set priority to my own template files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see [django-templateloaderwithpriorities](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-templateloaderwithpriorities) or [django-smart-extends](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-smart-extends)

Comment: [django-apptemplates](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-apptemplates) is another possibility.