# Allow multiple apps to use {% extend base.html %} in Django without clashing?

Tags: django, templates, django-allauth, template-inheritance

I have only started with Django recently, and assume there must be a good solution for this issue!

After installing django-allauth through pip, it tried to extend `base.html` from my `project/templates` folder rather than from its own subdirectory. [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526314/django-allauth-loads-wrong-base-html-template) had the same issue and was told to rename one of the `base.html` files and then update all references to it in the related app templates. For a complex app (already bad), this is error-prone; it's even worse if multiple third party apps are each defining their own `base.html` and referring to it simply as `{% extends 'base.html' %}`. Also, I think this only applies to third party apps, since I can easily name base.html something different for each of my own apps, but I don't want to mess around with 3rd party apps that work.

My question is: **is there a safe/easy way to allow multiple third-party apps to use `{% extends 'base.html' %}` without clashing**?

I have read the docs on [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#template-loaders) in Django and understand that:

- By default, templates are loaded from the filesystem first, and then from app subdirectories. Therefore my `projects/templates` directory, which is defined in my `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting, will be called first; hence the django-allauth problem.
- I can reverse this order for the app subdirectory to be called first, by changing the order of `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`. However, this just means that *my website* will now extend the wrong `base.html`.

Although I can fix the current clash by renaming allauth's `base.html` as `allauthbase.html` and changing child template references to it as `{% extends 'allauthbase.html' %}`, this seems bulky.

Most wierdly, [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565751/override-a-django-third-party-application-template-through-extend) is complaining that each app extends its own base.html by default, but that seems impossible...

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an open issue related to the problem:
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/370

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen this. Still, I'd like to know if there's a solution, or if such apps are just considered to be poorly designed.